# Math problem in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I had been carefully following Bishop's Pattern Recognition book and came across some of difficulties due to my merely basic math ground.First begin by the Gaussian section on page 80.

> The functional dependence of the Gaussian on x is through the quadratic form
>   Δ2 = (x − μ)TΣ-1(x − μ) (2.44)
>   which appears in the exponent. The quantity Δ is called the Mahalanobis distance
>   from μ to x and reduces to the Euclidean distance whenΣis the identity matrix. The
>   Gaussian distribution will be constant on surfaces in x-space for which this quadratic
>   form is constant.

What exactly is a constant quadratic form and distribution?How could (2.44) a constant.

And in page 82,

> We now look at the moments of the Gaussian distribution and thereby provide an
>   interpretation of the parameters μ and Σ. The expectation of x under the Gaussian
>   distribution is given by
>
> [image: the equation]
>
> where we have changed variables using z = x − μ. We now note that the exponent
>   is an even function of the components of z and, because the integrals over these are
>   taken over the range (−∞,∞), the term in z in the factor (z + μ) will vanish by
>   symmetry.Thus
>   E[x] = μ (2.59)

And I could not see the magic from (2.58) to (2.59).

Another one regarding beta distribution.Why beta distribution has a probability more than 1 on its y-axis?

Sorry if all these sound stupid but it had been in my head for days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three questions really should be asked as three distinct questions.

1) Since the multivariate Gaussian distribution has density $$ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2}|\mathbf\Sigma|^{1/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf x}-{\mathbf\mu})^T{\mathbf\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\mathbf\mu})\right),$$

those $\mathbf x$ for which $({\mathbf x}-{\mathbf\mu})^T{\mathbf\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\mathbf\mu})$ takes a given value will have the same density.

2) Letting $\mathbf z = {\mathbf x}-{\mathbf\mu}$ means the multivariate Gaussian distribution for $\mathbf z$ is symmetric about $\mathbf 0$ and so has an expectation of $\mathbf 0$.  Using that, plus the integral of the whole density being $1$, allows you to see that the expectation of $\mathbf x$ is $\mathbf\mu$.

3) The beta distribution does not have a probability of more than $1$: it has a probability **density** more than $1$ in part of its support.  Since it is restricted to taking values in the range $[0,1]$ and the integral of its density is $1$, this is inevitable (apart from the case of a uniform distribution).